# AngularJS/Ionic - ion-nav-view vs ion-view

Tags: ionic-framework

Please can somebody clarify when I would use an `ion-nav-view` opposed to an `ion-view`? I am learning AngularJS/Ionic (I have a basic understanding of AngularJS; and would like to use Ionic to enhance it).

I understand the `ion-nav-view` implements the AngularUI Router service(?) which is a must in order to have nested views within views. But the documentation does not make clear where I should be using one or the other?

All the documentation states for `ion-view` is:
A container for content, used to tell a parent ionNavBar about the current view.

But I have seen an `ion-view` used outside navbar interface.

So what gives?

Answer (score 16):

`ion-nav-view` is the place where your `ion-view`s get injected to.
You can see `ion-nav-view` as the frame where your paint, the `ion-view`, is gonna be painted on by the `$stateProvider`.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Not that I don't believe you; :) I'd just love to learn a bit more.  So many Angular/Ionic resources are way too heavy - I'd love a high-level overview of things to help me get started quickly.

Answer (score -7):

Open the template menu.html

Search for

```
ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable"
```

and change it to

```
ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable bar-royal"
```